# Asymptotic error expansion of global error for single step methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

My question refers to the proof of the following theorem, but it may suffice to just skip the theorem and continue with the problematic taylor expansion $(\ast)$:

> Let $f(t,y)$ and the single step method $\varphi(t,u,h)$ be sufficiently often continuously differentiable and let the local error have an expansion of the form
>   $$ le(t,h) = d_{p+1}(t)h^{p+1} + d_{p+2}(t)h^{p+2} + \cdots + d_{N+1}(t)h^{N+1} + \mathcal{O}(h^{N+2}). $$
>   Then, the global error $e_h(t)$ after $n$ steps with size $h$ at $t^* = t_0 + nh$ has an asymptotic expansion
>   $$e_h(t^*) = e_p(t^*)h^p + e_{p+1}(t^*)h^{p+1} + \cdots + e_N(t^*)h^N + E_{N+1}(t^*,h)h^{N+1},$$
>   where $E_{N+1}(t^*,h)$ for $0<h\leq h_0$ is bounded.

In the proof, a Taylor expansion is carried out

$$\varphi(t,y(t),h) - \varphi(t,y(t) - e_p(t)h^p,h)
=
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \varphi(t,y(t),h)e_{p}h^p + \mathcal{O}(h^{2p}) \tag{$\ast$}
$$

which I don't understand. Apparently, this is a Taylor expansion of a function of $h$ at $0$. But if I consider the function

$\varphi \circ g$, where
$$g(h) := (t,y(t) - e_p(t)h^p,h)^T$$ then the Jacobian is
$$J_g(h) = (0,-pe_p(t)h^{p-1},1)^T$$ 
wheras the Jacobian of $\varphi$ is
$$J_{\varphi}(x,y,h) = (\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial \varphi}{ \partial h})$$
The chainrule would yield $J_{\varphi \circ g} = J_\varphi \cdot J_g$ which does not correspond to the result at $(\ast)$.

Do you have any suggestions on how to interpret $(\ast)$ correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Taylor expansion is for
$$
φ(t,y(t),h)−φ(t,y(t)−s,h)=\frac{∂}{∂y}φ(t,y(t),h)s+O(s^2)
$$
where $s=e_p(t)h^p$ so that $O(s^2)=O(h^{2p})$.